# Duplicated Results on SQL Query

Tags: php, html, mysql

PHP newbie here! I ve been struggling with this for a few days now and i have decided i cant figure this out on my own.

Basically i have 2 database tables "projects_2016" and "attachment".

I want to show the data of "projects_2016" to show in the top table and then check for a matching id number (and if it exsits) in "attachment" it will list all the results under the "project_2016 data".

At the moment it works great but it duplicates the "projects_2016" data for every "attachment" entry.

Here is my code, any input is appreciated!

PS not too concereded about Sql injections. Still learning that!

```
<?php include '../../../connection_config.php'; 

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM attachment JOIN projects_2016 ON             attachment.attachment_ABE_project_number = projects_2016.id ORDER BY `attachment_ABE_project_number` DESC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>

<table width="20" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th height="0" scope="col"><table width="990" border="0" align= "center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="text_report">
          <td width="107" height="30" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><strong>PNo</strong></td>
          <td width="871" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><strong>Project Name</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="20" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text_report"><strong><?php echo "<br>". $row["ID"]. "<br>";?></strong></td>
          <td height="20" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor= "#FFFFFF" class="text_report"><strong><?php echo "<br>". $row["project_name"]. "<br>";?></strong></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
        <?php  

$photo_id = $row["ID"];

$contacts = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM attachment WHERE attachment_ABE_project_number = '$photo_id'" ;

$result_contacts = $conn->query($contacts);

if ($result_contacts->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row_contacts = $result_contacts->fetch_assoc()) {

?>
        <table width="990" border="0" align="center" cellpadding=   "3" cellspacing="0" class="text_report">
          <tr>
            <td height="0" colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="319" height="30" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><strong>File Name</strong></td>
            <td width="279" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><strong>File Type</strong></td>
            <td width="315" align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><strong>File Size (KB)</strong></td>
            <td width="53" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><strong>View File</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row_contacts ['file'] ?></td>
            <td height="20" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row_contacts ['type'] ?></td>
            <td height="20" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row_contacts ['size'] ?></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="/../gauteng/uploads/<?php echo $row_contacts ['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="0" colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <?php
}
?>
        </table>
        <?php        



}
?></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <th height="26"> </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <?php        


 }

 }
?>
  </p>
</table> 

<?php   $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is oxymoronic

Comment: That's how the join works.  For each attachment, there will be multiple repeated project records.  Instead of a join, maybe do an "exist" in your where statement.  Check out : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Thank you JustAspMe !!!! Worked 100%! here is the code that works.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects_2016
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM attachment WHERE projects_2016.id =  attachment_ABE_project_number) ORDER BY `id` DESC  ";

Comment: Hmm, I just re-read the question.  Actually you want to list projects even through there are no attachments, correct?  Using the exists in the where clause will omit projects that have no attachments.

Comment: No Just the opposite, your exists works perfect thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects_2016
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM attachment WHERE projects_2016.id =  attachment_ABE_project_number) ORDER BY `id` DESC  ";